# Sorry, but "MiKTeX Compiler Driver" did not succeed. texify: major issue: So far, no MiKTeX administrator has checked for updates

Tags: bibtex, miktex2.9, miktex-update

My .tex files generate PDF correctly for other users.In my MikTex installation , when i use the option for PdfLaTex+makeIndex+BibTex, it results in error, pdfLatex creates PDF without index.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: don't use texify if you get errors.  Run pdflatex and other tools one by one directly to get better error messages.

Comment: When I run BibTex separately I dont see any process happen and nothing printed in logs

Comment: bibtex writes it log into a file with the ending blg. And the best is to run on a command line, then you always see something.

Comment: I am new to MikTex so can you show me link to how to run on command-line,Currently I am generating PDF using Texworks